# Rails: Iterate a tree-like data model "from the inside out" while displaying only parent branches that have some data inside

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, performance, query-optimization

I have the following data model:

- A `Virtue` has_many `Rule`s
- A `Rule` has_many `Pattern`s
- A `Pattern` has_many `Issue`s

In addition, an `Issue` belongs_to a `Website` (i.e. the `Website` has_many `Issue`s).

Now I want to display all `Issue`s of a `Website` like this (added markdown syntax to make it more clear):

```
# My great report for Website X

## Virtue 1

### Rule 1.1

#### Pattern 1.1.3

(All the issues of Website X with pattern 1.1.3)

### Rule 1.3

## Virtue 2

### Rule 2.1

#### Pattern 2.1.1

(All the issues of Website X with pattern 2.1.1)

#### Pattern 2.1.2

(All the issues of Website X with pattern 2.1.2)

## Virtue 4

### Rule 4.3

#### Pattern 4.3.17

(All the issues of Website X with pattern 4.3.17)
```

As you can see, I don't want to display any `Virtue`, `Rule`, or `Pattern` that does not contain any `Issue`s. And that's the tricky part: **How do I iterate over all these elements, knowing already in the "outer" elements whether they have the relevant "inner" elements (`Issue`s)**?

If I wanted to display just **everything** (regardless whether there are findings inside), I could just iterate over each and every element in the tree.

```rb
# In some .erb file
Virtue.with_findings.each do |virtue|
  <%= virtue.name =>
  virtue.rules_with_findings.each do |rule|
    <%= rule.name =>
    rule.patterns_with_findings.each do |pattern|
      <%= pattern.name =>
      pattern.findings.each do |finding|
        <%= finding.map(&:name).to_sentence =>
      end
    end
  end
end
```

But now I need to know whether the current `Virtue` has `Findings` inside, which means that the virtue needs to ask the `Rule` whether it has `Findings` inside, and the `Rule` needs to ask the `Pattern`. This leads to a myriad of additional (very similar) database queries which decreases the performance a lot.

How would you solve this problem? I feel that I need to create some intelligent mechanism that first fetches all data from the database, and then has its own logic that relies on Ruby only (without fetching anything more from the database).

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Thats what [indirect assocations](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) are for:

```
class Virtue < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :rules
  has_many :patterns, through: :rules
  has_many :issues, through: :patterns
end
```

If you want to fetch only the virtues that have issues you would just do an INNER JOIN:

```
Virtue.joins(:issues)
```

Rails will figure out how to join through the intermediary tables and an inner join will limit the result to rows that have matches in the issues table.

> I feel that I need to create some intelligent mechanism that first fetches all data from the database, and then has its own logic that relies on Ruby only (without fetching anything more from the database).

This is a known problem known as the N+1 query issue where each iteration of a loop creates an additional database query.

In Rails it can be solved with methods like [`eager_load`, `preload` and `include`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations). They fetch the assocatiated data either in a single query or just one additional query instead of N+1.

Also you should avoid performing database queries from the view. The view should just take data from the controller and render it in the simplest way possible. In this case with something like a russian doll of partials instead of a monster view.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @max. I look into this - it's great to see how many features Rails offers under the hood that solve many problems that I did not yet even realise I had. 

Comment: After studying your response and the mentioned links, I see that they offer a solution to reduce strain on the database (which would increase general performance). This is nice. But I'm still unsure how to know "on the outside" about the data "on the inside": do you think it's a good idea to have such `*_with_finding` methods? How should their internals look like?

Comment: Both are very broad questions. Encapsulating your queries in methods in the model is generally a good idea. Join and eager loading are both tools to optimize the amount of round trips to the database - but like any tool its use depends entirely on the job at hand.